# How to view javascript tags in vim using tagbar + jsctags + tern_for_vim + ctags_exuberant?

Tags: microsoft-windows, filetype-javascript, ctags, plugin-tagbar

I'm writing javascript code using vim and I really like to have outline view for the current javascript file I'm editing. I find tagbar is the popular plugin for this purpose. And on its wiki, for javascript to work, it recommends jsctags depends on Tern.

Now

1. I have installed vim plugins: tagbar and tern_for_vim.
2. I've installed exuberant ctags and put its bin into path
3. I have installed jsctags

I open a js file in vim, and open the tagbar outline view, but there's no tags showing.

So I try running jsctags against a js file in command line directly, still, nothing is outputted.

has anyone successfully make this combination work? Can someone share some thoughts?

Comment: So what's your question exactly? You followed some instructions somewhere (where? what exactly did you do?) and something doesn't work (what?) as you're expecting (what did you expect?)

Comment: Part of the process Aaron didn't mention is actually generating the tags file.  That might be possible by running something on the shell: `jsctags *.js **/*.js`

Comment: Your question is better after your edit ;-) But I think this question would probably get better answers if you would include a (small) vimrc file and (small) JS file that clearly demonstrate the problem. This would reduce the effort required by the potential answerer to get started in investigating your problem ;-)

Comment: @joeytwiddle The Tagbar plugin uses the external tools to create its own tags file. You shouldn't need to do it manually on the command line.

Comment: I've rolled back your Rev 4 → 3. Please post the resolution as a self-answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
:g/func/#
```

gives you an actionable outline of the current JavaScript buffer without installing any third party plugin or requiring any external program.

Use `func\|var` to include variable declarations.

Comment: What do you mean "actionable"? Or more specifically, what actions can I take, and how?

Comment: I suppose typing `:[line_number]` is the obvious action. I can also yank the last line with `/y` or delete all of them with `/d`. (I just stumbled across the holy grail.) Is there any way to yank all the lines?

Comment: @joeytwiddle, yes, `:23<CR>` is the obvious one. You can use `:g//y A` to yank all the lines in the output to register `a`.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a set of CTAGS regex rules for JavaScript and CoffeeScript. My rules include unit tests so I think they are more reliable than most.

Here's my git repo which should be most up to date:
    https://github.com/winstonwolff/ctags-javascript-coffeescript

And here are the rules I use as of writing this post:

```
--languages=-JavaScript
--langdef=js
--langmap=js:.js
--regex-js=/^var[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9._$]+) = \[/\1/a,array/
--regex-js=/^var[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9._$]+) = \{/\1/o,object/
--regex-js=/^var[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*=[^{\[]*$/\1/r,var/

--regex-js=/^var[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*[A-Za-z0-9_$]+.extend/\1/f,function/
--regex-js=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]*\.)*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*function/\2/f,function/
--regex-js=/^[ \t]*function[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*\(/\1/f,function/
--regex-js=/^[ \t]*var[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_$]*\.)*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]function/\2/f,function/

--regex-js=/(jQuery|\$)\([ \t]*([^ \t]*)[ \t]*\)\.bind\([ \t]*['"](.*)['"]/\2.\3/f,function/

--regex-js=/^[ \t]*describe[ \t]*\([ \t]*["'](.*)["']/\1/f,function/
--regex-js=/^([ \t]*)(describe|context|it)[ \t]*\([ \t]*["'](.*)["']/.\1\3/f,function/
```