# Getting tags to show in tagbar for JS file

Tags: tags, ctags

I've been trying in vain the past few days to get Vim to recognize tags in my JS file. My problem is very similar to this other question: [How to view javascript tags in vim using tagbar + jsctags + tern_for_vim + ctags_exuberant?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/how-to-view-javascript-tags-in-vim-using-tagbar-jsctags-tern-for-vim-ctags) and I have a similar setup:

1. Universal ctags installed (since exuberant-ctags seems to be not updating as much)
2. Jsctags via a global gem
3. tern_for_vim

I've tried to debug the tagbar plugin and it seems to call `jsctags` fine and does not print any errors. I've also tried to run `jsctags` via the command line with this command per the git repo's [readme](https://github.com/ramitos/jsctags):

```
find . -type f -iregex ".*\.js$" -not -path "./node_modules/*" -exec jsctags {} -f \; | sed '/^$/d' | sort > tags
```

This generates a tags file fine, and if I run `echo tagfiles()` the output gives me `['tags']`, which means it's pointing to the correct tag file location (confirmed using `:pwd`). `:tag` gives me `tag stack empty` and if I put my cursor over any method or object and hit `Ctrl-]` I'll get `tag not found: Controller`.

I've referenced [Can't get Ctags working](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/cant-get-ctags-working) and [How to view javascript tags in vim using tagbar + jsctags + tern_for_vim + ctags_exuberant?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/how-to-view-javascript-tags-in-vim-using-tagbar-jsctags-tern-for-vim-ctags), both of which don't have solutions, hence the question here.

Attaching a section of my `.vimrc` to show my list of plugins, js file and `.ctags` if relevant:

**.vimrc**

```
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim' " Plugin Management
Plugin 'tmhedberg/matchit' " Matching configuration for %
Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax' " Additional JS syntax highlighting
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround' "provides mappings to easily delete, change and add surroundings like quotes, parenths etc
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown' "Markdown support
Plugin 'davidoc/taskpaper.vim' "Taskpaper support
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary' " Simple commenting in vim 
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree' "Tree navigation
Plugin 'Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin' "Nerdtree git tags for files support
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic' "Syntax check
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar' "Browse the tags of the current file and get an overview of its structure.
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim' "Full path fuzzy file, buffer, mru, tag, ... finder for Vim.
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline' "Statusbar 
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive' "Vim wrapper, allow for git viewing in airline
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes' "Airline themes
Plugin 'burnettk/vim-angular' " Angular functionality
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs' "Insert or delete brackets, parens, quotes in pair
Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine' "A vim plugin to display the indention levels with thin vertical lines
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized' "Solarized color theme
Plugin 'chriskempson/vim-tomorrow-theme' "Tomorrow color theme
Plugin 'w0ng/vim-hybrid' "Hybrid Solarized, codecademy, Jellybeans, and Tomorrow-Night
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe' " Code completion 
Plugin 'marijnh/tern_for_vim' "Vim tern usage, greatly improves YouCompleteMe JS use
Plugin 'elzr/vim-json' " JSON highlighting 
Plugin 'rking/ag.vim' " Advanced searching 
" For JavaScript development
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript' "Javascript syntax highlighting
Plugin 'moll/vim-node' " Node js 
Plugin 'groenewege/vim-less' " Less syntax
Plugin 'othree/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim' " Javascript syntax library highlighting
Plugin 'othree/jspc.vim' " Javascript parameter completion
Plugin '1995eaton/vim-better-javascript-completion' " Expansion of vim's javascript syntax file for HTML5
```

**.ctags**

```
--recurse=yes
--exclude=.git
--exclude=vendor/*
--exclude=node_modules/*
--exclude=db/*
--exclude=log/*
--exclude=*.min.js
--exclude=*.css

--langdef=less
--langmap=less:.less
--regex-less=/^[ t ]*.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/1/c,class,classes/
--regex-less=/^[ t ]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/1/i,id,ids/
--regex-less=/^[ t ]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ tn, ]+)+){/1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-less=/^[ t ]*@medias+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/1/m,media,medias/

--languages=-JavaScript
--langdef=js
--langmap=js:.js


--regex-js=/[ \t. ]([A-Z][A-Z0-9._$]+)[ \t ]*[=:][ \t ]*([0-9"'\[\{]|null)/\1/n,constant/
--regex-js=/\.([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t ]*=[ \t ]*\{/\1/o,object/
--regex-js=/['"]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)['"]*[ \t ]*:[ \t ]*\{/\1/o,object/
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)\[["']([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)["']\][ \t ]*=[ \t ]*\{/\1\.\2/o,object/

--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t ]*=[ \t ]*\(function\(\)/\1/c,class/
--regex-js=/['"]*([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)['"]*:[ \t ]*\(function\(\)/\1/c,class/
--regex-js=/class[ \t ]+([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t ]*/\1/c,class/
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z$][A-Za-z0-9_$()]+)[ \t ]*=[ \t ]*[Rr]eact.createClass[ \t ]*\(/\1/c,class/
--regex-js=/([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t ]*=[ \t ]*[A-Za-z0-9_$]*[ \t ]*[{(]/\1/c,class/
--regex-js=/([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t ]*:[ \t ]*[A-Za-z0-9_$]*[ \t ]*[{(]/\1/c,class/

--regex-js=/([A-Za-z$][A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t ]*=[ \t ]*function[ \t ]*\(/\1/f,function/
--regex-js=/(function)*[ \t ]*([A-Za-z$_][A-Za-z0-9_$]+)[ \t ]*\([^)]*\)[ \t ]*\{/\2/f,function/
--regex-js=/['"]*([A-Za-z$][A-Za-z0-9_$]+)['"]*:[ \t ]*function[ \t ]*\(/\1/m,method/
--regex-js=/([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)\[["']([A-Za-z0-9_$]+)["']\][ \t ]*=[ \t ]*function[ \t ]*\(/\2/m,method/
```

**js file**

```
define(['jquery',
        'lodash',
        'backbone',
        'mobile/chart/model/chart-model',
        'mobile/chart/views/chart-view',
        'services/analytic-service'],
    function ($, _, Backbone, ChartModel, ChartView, AnalyticsService) {
        'use strict';
        // not exactly like the full chart controller
        //jshint unused:false
        function log(msg) {
            console.log('%c' + msg, 'font-size:12pt; color: #30F');
        }
        //jshint unused:true

        function newGuid(noDashes) {
            var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
                var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
                return v.toString(16);
            });
            return noDashes ? guid.replace(/-/g, '') : guid;
        }

        function parseJson(jsonString) {
            //our JSON may include long integer numbers that can have more digits
            // than the JS Number type supports. These numbers are all IDs so we
            // can convert them to strings before parsing.
            var massagedJson = jsonString.replace(/([^\\]{1})\":(?: {0,})([0-9]{16,})([^\.])/g, "$1\":\"$2\"$3");
            //JSON docs are not supposed to have NaN or nan but some of our servers are adding them anyway.
            massagedJson = massagedJson.replace(/([^\\]{1})\":(?: {0,})(nan)/gi, "$1\":\"NaN\"");
            return JSON.parse(massagedJson);
        }

        function processHistoricalData(data) {
            if(this.isDestroyed) {
                return;
            }

            var bars = data.bars,
                subscription = this.subscriptions[data.subscriptionId];

            if (_.isUndefined(this.earliestTickReceived) && data.requestIsFinal) {
                this.model.set('lastError', 'Contract has no historical data');
                this.model.set('noHistoricalData', true);
                return;
            }

            this.model.set({
                'requestIsPending': data.requestIsPending,
                'requestIsFinal': data.requestIsFinal,
                'requestIsCompleted': data.requestIsCompleted,
                'lastError': null,
                'retryingConnection': false,
                'remainingRetries': 5
            });

            if (bars && bars.length > 0) {
                if (bars.length > 0) {
                    // The server can return an array of bars which only have inside market updates. In this
                    // case the converted bars array will be empty.
                    subscription.earliestTickReceived = new Date(bars[0].tickTime);
                }
            } else {
                bars = [];
            }

            this.view.historicalData(bars);
        }

        function processLiveData(data) {
            if(this.isDestroyed) {
                return;
            }
            this.view.liveData(data.bars);
        }

        function isVAP(name) {
            return (name.indexOf('VAP') > -1);
        }

        var Controller = function (Host, $chartEl) {
            var self = this,
                uniqueId = null,
                onErrorHandler = null,
                onClosedHandler = null,
                onConnectedHandler = null,
                onHistoricalDataHandler = null,
                onLiveDataHandler = null;
        this.analyticsService = new AnalyticsService({
            analyticsUrl: analyticsUrl,
            accessToken: Host.getAuthToken(),
            logDebug: function () {
                console.log.apply(console, arguments);
            }
        });

        this.model = new ChartModel();
        uniqueId = this.model.getUniqueId();
        this.view = new ChartView({
            model: this.model,
            el: $chartEl[0],
            $el: $chartEl,
            controller: this
        });

        onErrorHandler = function (err) {
            self.Host.dismissProgress();
            self.model.set('retryingConnection', false);
            self.model.set('firstHistoricalCallbackIteration', true);
            self.model.set('retryingConnection', false);

            if (err && err.error) {
                self.model.set('lastError', err.error);
                self.Host.log('Analytics Server Error: ' + err.error);
            }
            else {
                self.model.set('lastError', 'Analytics Server Error');
                self.Host.log('Analytics Server Error, unspecified reason');
            }
        };
   });
```

Thanks all and please let me know if I need to provide any additional details.

Comment: 1. The Tagbar plugin reads the output of ctags-like programs directly, *without using any pre-existing `tags` file*, and processes that data independently. Everything tags-related it does or doesn't is completely separated from anything tag-related Vim does or doesn't. **So… is your question about Vim or about Tagbar?**

Comment: 2. You mention Universal Ctags, JSCtags, and the mostly unrelated tern_for_vim, but you show a convoluted JSCtags example and your `~/.ctags` file. **So… is your question about JSCtags or about Universal Ctags?**

Comment: 3. Vim expects your `tags` file to adhere to a specific format described in `:help ctags`. **Does the output of your shell command fit that format?**

Comment: 4. You can use `:echo taglist(".")` to output what Vim could put together from the files in `tagfiles()`. **Can you find your objects/methods, there?**

Comment: @romainl. Thanks for the thoughts and sorry for the confusing information. I'm new to tagging in vim :-). Overall the objective is how to get tags to show up in Tagbar so I can have an overview and easy navigation of my file. Universal ctags and jsctags are apparently used by tagbar to auto-generate the tags (at least that's what I understood). If that's not possible then to use Vim's native tag functionality.

Comment: @romainl `echo taglist(".")` prints out a huge list of tags that I don't know how to search within so I tried looking for a specific method like `:tag processLiveData` with no luck. Also, I'm not able to run `:help ctags` so I'm not sure what format you're referring to. There are definitely tags being generated for some files but not all. No difference in syntax of the files, but it's strange that my lib/ folder is getting tagged yet the folder with all my work files (widgets/) is not...

Comment: Tagbar uses *either* ctags *or* jsctags. Which one it uses is probably defined by some option described somewhere in `:help tagbar`. What tags you have listed in the Tagbar window *may or may not be the same seen by Vim itself.* The operation of tags in Vim is totally separated from that in Tagbar so using one for debugging the other makes no sense at all.

Comment: Right. tagbar is calling jsctags with no errors printing within it's debugging log. Vim also uses the tags file generated by ctags or jsctags for it's tag functionality so no, I didn't think that using one to debug the other was such a stretch but I understand why that may lead to false positives.